# System.Object in C#, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

I don't really understand the second question, **is my answer to the second question correct**?

1. Which of the following is not a method of System.Object?
2. **What is the most generic (least derived) interface or subclass of System.Object of which it is a method**?
   a. GetType()
   b. ToString()
   c. Equals(object obj)
   d. Clone()

**My Answers**:

Clone() is not a method of System.Object.

ICloneable for Clone. System.Object is the root type, the rest of the methods are its direct members.

**What is the answer to the second question? What does it mean?**

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Looks good to me...what's the question?

Comment: The wording of that second question is confusing. It's asking you what class or interface the `Clone` method is a member of.

Comment: why on earth did you make this question an image?

Comment: @Johan, [here's a good guess](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141752/how-to-handle-images-containing-text-vs-text/141754#comment401461_141752)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your answer to the first question is of course correct. [Proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx).

The second question means, that if you had interface `IExtendedCloneable` which would derive from  `ICloneable` (had `ICloneable` as parent interface), it would not be a corect answer, because ICloneable is more generic (less derived) - it is closer to `object` on the inheritance tree.

If there wasn't that restriction, you could say that `Clone()` is a member of    [System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) and you would be right, but the answer wouldn't be really relevant.

Thanks to that restriction, `ICloneable` is the answer.

Comment: I argue that because question asks subclass or interface of System.Object, IExtendedCloneable is a custom type, which the question does not intend to ask. I think ICloneable is the answer.

Comment: Even if IExtendedCloneable derive from ICloneable, ICloneable is still the answer. Please point it out if i am wrong.

Comment: @PingPong I made up IExtendedCloneable to ilustrate "he most generic (least derived) interface or subclass" that has Clone(). I couldn't come up with any interface that derives from ICloneable from top off my head. Of course ICloneable is the answer, because it is less generic than ICloneable.